# Putting an "irregular" box shadow on a heading in CSS 3

Tags: css, box-shadow

I have an h2 heading with a background image as seen bellow:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.title {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 4px 20px 4px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yco0r.png') center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
```

Since the website is responsive, the image would have to stretch or contract. So I would rather replace it with a *purely CSS* box-shadow.

I managed to obtain the effect below:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.section_title {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="content_section">
  <h2 class="section_title">About us</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quod repudiandae cupiditate reprehenderit, error aspernatur labore cumque. Optio natus dolores molestiae molestias non totam corrupti.</p>
</div>
```

But unfortunately, it has a regular form, instead of "taller" in the middle, like the one I used an image for.

What am I missing?

Comment: You aren't missing anything. This isn't possible with regular CSS properties though I believe it can be done with trickery. I don't do trickery.

Comment: So your real question is"how do I achieve the image with an actual box-shadow"...or alternative.

Comment: https://paulund.co.uk/learn-css-box-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element to achieve this effect, using border-radius:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.section_title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section_title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% - 12px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 4px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.section_title::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_section">
  <h2 class="section_title">About us</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quod repudiandae cupiditate reprehenderit, error aspernatur labore cumque. Optio natus dolores molestiae molestias non totam corrupti.</p>
</div>
```

Drawbacks: You must define a `background-color` on the `::after` pseudo-element to the same as your background, in order to cover the top part of the shadow. You could try using `clip` and forget the `::after` element but it doesn't have full cross-browser support. Also the values are hard-coded, you could adjust with percentages and `rem`/`em` (as box-shadow doesn't support percentage length values).

Answer (score 1):

Let see if it works for you

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.section_title {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 56px -21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="content_section">
  <h2 class="section_title">About us</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quod repudiandae cupiditate reprehenderit, error aspernatur labore cumque. Optio natus dolores molestiae molestias non totam corrupti.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks beautiful, but it does not have that _triange_ shape the original one has.

Comment: Then try adding :after in h2. Make it 80% of the container. You might get better results.

Answer (score 1):

What about a radial-gradient and much less code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 4px 20px 4px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top, #ddd, transparent) 0 100%/100% 4px no-repeat;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, odit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quod repudiandae cupiditate reprehenderit, error aspernatur labore cumque. Optio natus dolores molestiae molestias non totam corrupti.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun one! What I did was I created an oval with no border and a box shadow. Then absolutely positioned it under the header. This solution is responsive and tested on Chrome and Edge and looks closest to the final result you're going for. I added some comments to explain what each of the styles are doing for clarity. JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/buzuje/edit?html,css,output

```css
:root {
  --header-size: 20px;
  --body-font-size: 16px;
  --gutter: 10px;
  --gutter-lg: 20px;
  --oval-height: 15px;
  --oval-bottom-adjustment: 0px;
  --oval-blur: 12px;
  --oval-spread: 3px;
  --box-shadow-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

body {
  background: white;
  font-size: var(--header-size);
}

.section-title {
  
  /* basic styling */
  font-size: var(--header-size);
  font-weight: bold;  
  padding: var(--gutter);
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* 
    This enables us to assign this as the containing box 
    for the manually postioned children to this element 
  */
  position: relative;
}


.oval {
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--oval-bottom-adjustment));
  
  /* comment this out or set to 1 to see the full oval being clipped */
  z-index: -1;

  /* 
    Because the containing box is the padding box for absolutely positioned 
    children, modify the width to account for the padding. 10.1.4.1: 
    https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details 
  */
  width: calc(100% - 2*var(--gutter));
  
  /* 
    This defines how "squished" your oval is. Higher makes the oval taller 
    and more 'pointed' 
  */
  height: var(--oval-height);
  
  /* h-offset v-offset blur spread color */
  box-shadow: 0 0 var(--oval-blur) var(--oval-spread) var(--box-shadow-color);
}

p {
  margin: var(--gutter-lg);
  font-size: var(--body-font-size);
}
```

```html
  <div class="content_section">
    
      <div class="section-title">
        About Us
        <div class="oval"></div>
      </div>
      
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, odit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quod repudiandae cupiditate reprehenderit, error aspernatur labore cumque. Optio natus dolores molestiae molestias non totam corrupti.</p>
    
  </div>
```